# expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: LBRACK[0m[0m in terraform

Tags: parsing, jenkins, continuous-integration, terraform

Being new to terraform and Jenkins, I am trying to run terraform script on jenkins but facing this strange issue as shown below:

> Checking out Revision 59b7e707924169b66e3043a381ab63f6ccd0e2ae
>   (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>
> > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >     git checkout -f 59b7e707924169b66e3043a381ab63f6ccd0e2ae
> >     git rev-list 14cca48b44d7820f3f6ea8ed6d2a0728bc5e2176 # timeout=10 [FT_packer] $ /opt/software/terraform/0.9.5/terraform get [31mError
> >     loading configuration: Error parsing
> >     /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-tf/farm_vpc_02/FT_packer/vars.tf:
> >     At 16:35: expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got:
> >     LBRACK[0m[0m FATAL: java.lang.Exception: Terraform Get failed: 1  at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.executeGet(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:224)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformBuildWrapper.setUp(TerraformBuildWrapper.java:256)
> >       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)  at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
> >       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)  at
> >     hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
> >     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
> >       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Main.tf looks like this :

```
resource "aws_instance" "FT-packer-node" {
  ami                           = "${var.aws-region}"
  instance_type                 = "${var.instance-type}"
  vpc_security_group_ids        = "${var.vpc-security-group-ids}"
  key_name                      = "${var.key-name}"
  subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet-id}"
  associate_public_ip_address   = "${var.associate-public-ip-address}"
  availability_zone             = "eu-central-1a"
  private_ip                    = "${var.machine-private-ip}"
  tags {
    Name                        = "${var.machine-name-node}"
    Owner                       = "${var.team-name}"
  }

  timeouts {
    create                      = "${var.create-timeout}"
    delete                      = "${var.update-timeout}"
  }
}
```

Declared all variables in vars.ft like below:

```
variable "access_key" {}

variable "secret_key" {}

# ------------- MACHINE RELATED CONFIGS ------------- 

variable "vpc-name" {}

# Key file(pep/ppk) to be associated
variable "key-name" {}

# EC2 instance size
variable "instance-type" {}

# VPC Security group id to launch machine in
variable "vpc-security-group-ids" []

# Subnet of the VPC
variable "subnet-id" {}

variable "elb-name" {}
# --------------------------ENDS-----------------------------------------


# ------------------------ Optionals ----------------------------------------
# Below configs can be left unchanged. Change on need basis only.
# Team name
variable "team-name" {}

variable "machine-name-node" {}

variable "machine-private-ip" {}

variable "create-timeout" {}

variable "update-timeout" {}

variable "availability-zones" {}

variable "elb-access-log-bucket-name" {}

variable "elb-access-log-dir-name" {}


variable "is-internal-lb" {}

# Need a public IP ?
variable "associate-public-ip-address" {}

# Region
variable "aws-region" {}
```

Error is been shown at the line 16 of above file, that is

> variable "vpc-security-group-ids" []

Actual resource variables are mentioned like this in jenkins :

[image]

Comment: `variable "vpc-security-group-ids" []` should be `variable "vpc-security-group-ids" {}`. Also you should remove those screenshots and paste the relevant text into code blocks instead so people can more easily parse and view things.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR ... by this `variable "vpc-security-group-ids" {}` change I am getting `variable vpc-security-group-ids should be type string, got list` this error. And I have updated the error screenshot to error text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second issue, seems the value of variable `vpc_security_group_ids` is a list.  **(Yes, it is, I can confirm now, from the screenshot)**

Do changes below

```
variable "vpc-security-group-ids" {
  type = "list"
}

resource "aws_instance" "FT-packer-node" {

  vpc_security_group_ids        = "${var.vpc-security-group-ids}"

}
```

Before you run `terraform plan/apply`, you should do a validation first

```
terraform validate -check-variables=false
```

This will be useful to fix your first issue

> Error loading configuration: Error parsing /opt/repository/jenkins/workspace/crspng-CCPDev-ccp-ft-tf/farm_vpc_02/FT_packer/**vars.tf**: At 16:35: expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: LBRACK

Comment: By doing the change like you said `vpc_security_group_ids        = "${var.vpc-security-group-ids}"`. I am getting the same error like `* variable vpc-security-group-ids should be type string, got list[0m[0m`. Also running the terraform validate locally not showing any error .

Comment: How to feed the value of `${var.vpc-security-group-ids}`

Comment: I am feeding at `Resource Variables (Optional)` in jenkins . Shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if this fix your issue or not.

Comment: After updating, timeout exception coming and no list parsing error this time like this `* aws_instance.FT-packer-node: [ERR] Error decoding timeout: Timeout Key (create) is not supported[0m[0m`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156014/discussion-between-jet-and-bmw).

Comment: Resolved `Timeout Key` issue by removing it from variables as it was not necessary. `variable "vpc-security-group-ids" {
  type = "list"
}` this helped me to come out of error. Thanks !